# Rotations of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to obtain a list of some of the rotations of the following string "I want to break free tonight". The constraint is that a rotation can not begin with the words "to" or "tonight". So the list of rotations is `["I want to break free today", "want to break free tonight I", "break free tonight I want to", "free tonight I want to break"]`.

I wrote the following functions:

```
rotate :: [l] -> [l]
rotate [] = []
rotate (x:xs) = (x:xs) ++ head(x:xs)

rotate1 :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotate1 xs = take (length xs) (iterate rotate xs)

main = do
print $ rotate1(words("I want to break free tonight"))
```

Running this code, I obtained all possible rotations, but they form a list of lists having elements like `["want", "I", "to", "break", "free", "tonight"]` which is different from the string `"want I to break free tonight"`. Also, I would want to see how I can drop the rotations that begin with the words `"to"`, `"tonight"`. I tried to use the filter function for the second part but I did not manage to solve the problem. Any help/hint is appreciated. I notice that I am a beginner in Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

> Running this code…

The code doesn't run.  It has type errors.

First of all, let's fix the formatting so it's easier to read, and remove the extra parentheses

```
rotate :: [l] -> [l]
rotate [] = []
rotate (x:xs) = (x:xs) ++ head (x:xs)

rotate1 :: [a] -> [[a]]
rotate1 xs = take (length xs) (iterate rotate xs)

main = print $ rotate1 (words "I want to break free tonight")
```

This is weird:

```
rotate (x:xs) = (x:xs) ++ head (x:xs)
```

First of all, `x:xs` is the entire list, and `x` is the head of the list.  For example, `rotate [1, 2, 3]` becomes:

```
rotate [1, 2, 3] = let x = 1
                       xs = [2, 3]
                   in (x:xs) ++ head (x:xs)

rotate [1, 2, 3] = (1:[2, 3]) ++ head (1:[2, 3])
rotate [1, 2, 3] = [1, 2, 3] ++ head [1, 2, 3]
rotate [1, 2, 3] = [1, 2, 3] ++ 1
                   -- type error
```

But `++` needs a list on both sides.  What you probably want here is:

```
rotate (x:xs) = xs ++ [x]
```

Which gives us:

```
rotate [1, 2, 3] = let x = 1
                       xs = [2, 3]
                   in xs ++ [x]
rotate [1, 2, 3] = [2, 3] ++ [1]
rotate [1, 2, 3] = [2, 3, 1]
```

This is the same as:

```
rotate x = tail x ++ [head x]
```

For the rest of your problem… the filter should be straightforward since there is a `filter` function which does exactly what you need, and the `unwords` function turns lists of words back into strings.

Answer (score 1):

You want the function `intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]` in `Data.List`.

From the hackage docs:

> intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]
>
> intercalate xs xss is equivalent to (concat (intersperse xs xss)). It
>   inserts the list xs in between the lists in xss and concatenates the
>   result.

In `ghci`

```
> import Data.List
> intercalate " " ["want", "I", "to", "break", "free", "tonight"] 
> "want I to break free tonight"
```

Comment: Or you can use `unwords` which is in Prelude.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I knew about the functions filter and intercalate or unwords, but my problem is that I must apply them to a list of lists. Since there are no instructions like while or for in Haskell, I have no idea how I can pass through the list and apply the functions to each element. For example, I can not use unwords([["I", "want", "to", "break", "free", "tonight"], ["want", "I", "to", "break", "free","tonight"]]) to obtain the list ["I want to break free tonight", "want I to break free tonight"].

Comment: In the off chance that this is still a concern, the function you want (to pass through the list and apply a function to each element) is "map". It takes a function and a list and applies that function to each element in the list, returning a new list.

In your case, you'd do 

map unwords [["I", "want", "to", "break", "free", "tonight"], ["want", "I", "to", "break", "free", "tonight"]]

to get ["I want to break free tonight", "want I to break free tonight"]